# Prove: $\liminf_{n \to \infty} s_n \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I am looking over examples and the definitions for this section but I am still not familiar with all the tricks. I appreciate any help with proving this (from hints to maybe a solution. It is only a review so I just need something to look at and make sure I am doing it right). Thank you.

> Prove $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} s_n \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n$$

Comment: I've edited your post to fix the MathJax. Please make sure that it's correct.

Comment: Thank you, I was just editing it trying to figure LaTeX out. I looked over what you did and will make sure to apply what I saw in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: for every $n$ we have $$\inf_{m \ge n}s_m \le \sup_{m \ge n}s_m$$

Edit: if the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is bounded then just take the limit and you are done.

If the sequence is not bounded make sure you are defining things in the following way:

set $\alpha_n = \inf_{m \ge n}s_m$ then define $$\liminf_{n \to \infty}s_n = \begin{cases}-\infty & \text{if}\ \alpha_n = -\infty\ \text{for all}\ n\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\alpha_n & \text{otherwise.}\ \end{cases}$$

Do the same for the limit superior and finally everything works. (this prevents you from meaningless things like taking the limit of $-\infty$) :D

Comment: See my first instinct is to take the limit of both sides, but I know that is wrong because it is too simplistic. I feel like I am not thinking of the right inequality to apply here? (P.S. Thank you)

Comment: The question makes sense only when both exist, then taking the limit is exactly what you have to do!

Comment: But all the information given was what I posted. Is it necessary to prove they exist or sufficient to just say Assume what you stated is true, then take the limit of both sides and say by definition we have our solution?

Comment: I am editing with more details, sorry if I confused you.

Comment: A little bit haha may we clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Let $s_{n}$ a sequence, for all $n$ and $m$, we have
$$C_{n}= \inf\limits_{k\ge n} s_{k} \le \sup\limits_{k\ge m} s_{k}=B_{m} $$
This is true, since if $p\ge \max\left\{n,m \right\}$, then 
$$s_{p}\in\left\{ a_{n},a_{n+1},\dots\right\} \bigcap \left\{ a_{m},a_{m+1},\dots\right\} $$
so $$\inf\limits_{k\ge n} s_{k} \le s_{p} \le \sup\limits_{k\ge m} s_{k}$$
as, $C_{n}\le B_{m}$ for all $m$, then  we have 
$$C_{n}\le \lim\limits _{n\rightarrow \infty} B_{n}$$
and for all $n$, ve have 
$$\lim\limits _{n\rightarrow \infty}C_{n}\le \lim\limits _{n\rightarrow \infty} B_{n}$$

Comment: Attention readers! This deserves more upvotes!

Comment: I think we should mention that we are dealing with sequences of extended real numbers, right?

Comment: Yes, I think too

Answer (score 2):

Just use the definitions of $\lim \sup s_n = L$and $\lim \inf s_n = l$ of the sequence $\{s_n\}$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ $k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $s_n > l - \epsilon$ $\forall$ $n>k_1$ and $s_n < l + \epsilon $ for infinitely many $n$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ $k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $s_n < L + \epsilon$ $\forall$ $n>k_2$ and $s_n < L - \epsilon $ for infinitely many $n$.

Thus for for any natural number $k > \max\{k_1, k_2\}$, $s_k > l -\epsilon$ and $s_k < L+\epsilon$.

So we shall get $l - \epsilon < s_n < L + \epsilon$ $\forall n > k$ Taking $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ we shall get $L \ge l$, i.e. $\lim \sup \geq \lim \inf$.

The above proof is valid when $\{s_n\}$ is a bounded sequence. We say $\{s_n\}$ is unbounded above when $\lim \sup s_n = \infty$ and unbounded below when $\lim \inf s_n = - \infty$. Proof is trivial in this case.

Comment: Beautiful solution!